# How to do pitch replacement in praat?

Tags: praat

I tried to replace the pitch, but nothing happened when I pressed "replace pitch tier"? 
In order to clone a pitch contour and apply it to a different signal (replacing its original pitch contour):

- select a sound in the objects window
- go to To Manipulation and create a manipulation object
- select it and go to  Extract pitch tier
- create a manipulation object of a second sound object (the one which will have its pitch replaced)
- select both the second manipulation object and the pitch tier of the first one, then press Replace pitch tier
- listen to the second manipulation object (Play), to which the pitch of the first one is now applied.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. The `Replace pitch tier` command has no obvious effect on the GUI, but it _does_ replace the Pitch tier of the selected Manipulation object with the selected PitchTier object, so something _did_ happen, even if you got no clear feedback. As for the answer to the question in the title, that's the bullet list you wrote (and note the last step, which makes sure that a change _did_ take place).